# Capture windows messages generated by an MFC app in plain C++ dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc, message

First of all: Is this even possible?

I have a third party dll that interfaces some hardware. It's written in MFC. I received (from the dll vendors) a sample Visual Studio 2010 solution which has only one project: An MFC application (.exe) which calls the third party dll in question. It works fine.

When I try to use the third party dll from my dll (which is plain C++, no MFC, no .NET), I can call its functions fine, but there's a catch: the sample MFC app seems to "override" MessageProc in order to capture certain messages that the third party dll generates. And though the dll has a function called "RegisterFuncCallback" and I use it, my callback never gets called.

So here's the problem: How can I capture those messages without creating an MFC app? (Is it even possible?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I made it. Here's how:

1. Create a class which inherits from CWnd
2. Declare a message map associating the desired messages and their handlers
3. When creating the Window, use the CreateEx function (I did it in my class's constructor), and pass it the HWND_MESSAGE flag in the last but one parameter. This will create the window as a "Message Window", that is, invisible.
4. Once I'm done initializing the window and the MFC dll, I call RunModalLoop on my hidden window, in a separate thread, since it's blocking. This fires up the message pump, and starts receiving the MFC dll's messages.

**Edit**: I could finally do it using just Win32 API. Here's my story, code included:
[Programate Algo Blog](http://programatealgo.blogspot.com/2011/05/c-capture-windows-messages-from-mfc-app.html). Don't worry, it's in English.

Comment: I have just realized that CWnd is an MFC class, so I didn't quite make it. But I'm satisfied with this solution

Comment: A colleague told me that what I was doing with CWnd is very easy to do with WinAPI/Win32 calls, so now I'm looking into that. When I finish, I'll blog about it and post a link here

Answer (score 3):

If the DLL works with Win32 messages you won't get around them. But you do not neccessarily need MFC for that, a simple WinAPI solution would suffice. MFC just wraps the Win32 API. If those messages aren't Win32 messages, you do not need a Win32 application.

Comment: That sounds better, Win32 should be much easier to encapsulate. And how can I do that? I tried using the SetWindowsHookEx function, but my callback still didn't get called...

Comment: I did something like this: `::SetWindowsHookEx(
  WH_GETMESSAGE,
  MyCallback,
  GetModuleHandle("MyDLL.DLL"),
  GetCurrentThreadId()
);`

Comment: As long as I do not know how this DLL really works, I cannot answer this. And also I'm not that much of a Win32 expert (I never used the above method, not to speek of messages from another DLL). I just wanted to say, that you don't need MFC for Win32 specific tasks, as it's just a wrapper for this.

Comment: I don't know how it works either, I don't have the source. I'll keep investigating the hooking approach